# Fonts Pixelated/Unreadable in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fonts

About a quarter of the fonts in Windows 7 are illegible. This includes all browsers too. In fact, as I type this it is very light though bearable. In many cases I simply cannot read the text at all. I have checked resolution, refresh rate, updated graphics driver, swapped monitors, vga cables, activated cleartype, disabled hardware acceleration, tried safe mode, no helvetica installed, etc. Nothing. I have been battling this issue for months. Any suggestions?

[image: Screenshot of illegible browser text. *Affects all browsers.]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I had to re-calibrate ClearType. If you don't know where this is just go to Start>Search, type ClearType and then press enter. Then activate and/or re-calibrate.